# Как добавить пользователя в свою telegram группу через MadelineProto?

Tags: php, madelineproto

Я создал группу в телеграм. Так же у меня есть несколько сотен логинов которых я хочу добавить в свою телеграм группу.

Я хочу сделать это через MadelineProto.

Нашел такой метод: [inviteToChannel](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/channels.inviteToChannel.html) , но как только я не пробовал, всегда выдает ошибку:

> Telegram returned an RPC error: The provided channel is invalid (400) (CHANNEL_INVALID)

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле все оказалось довольно просто:

```
$MadelineProto->messages->addChatUser(['chat_id' => xxxxx, 'user_id' => xxxx, 'fwd_limit' => 100]);
```